# Cannot print a pixel value when using waitKey()

Tags: c++, opencv

I was writing a code to apply a mask to an image.
Halfway through writing the code I realised that:

```
//applying a mask throughout the image using user defined function.
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void sharpen(Mat& src, Mat& dst)

{ cout<<"\n\nFunction just called\n\n";
/*for (int i=1; i<src.rows-1;i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<src.cols-1;j++)
        {
            //dst(i,j)=(-1*(src(i-1,j-1)+src(i-1,j)+src(i-1,j+1)+src(i,j-1)+src(i,j+1)+src(i+1,j-1)+src(i+1,j)+src(i+1,j+1))+8*src(i,j))/9;

        }

    }*/
dst=src;
imshow("src",src);
imshow("dst",dst);

//cout<<src;

}

int main()
{
Mat src,dst;

src=imread("/home/krishna/Downloads/door1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

namedWindow("src",WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("dst",WINDOW_NORMAL);
cout<<"\n\nHi\n\n";
cout<<(int)src.at<uchar>(155,155);
//sharpen(src,dst);
//waitKey(-1);
return 0;
}
```

If I de-comment `waitKey` and/or `sharpen()`, the pixel at (155,155) does not get printed. I've tried changing the data type of `src.at<>()`, but in vain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
cout<<(int)src.at<uchar>(155,155);
```

by:

```
cout<<(int)src.at<uchar>(155,155)<<endl;
```

This `std::endl` will inserts a new-line character and flushes the stream.

Also you can just use `std::flush` to flush the output stream.

Comment: @KrishnaChouthankar You are welcome. Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green)

Comment: There another issue that might need your help: adding the line ^dst.at<uchar>(j,i)=src.at<uchar>(j,i);^ gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: @KrishnaChouthankar You should check that `i` and `j` do not exceed the bounds of both, `src` and `dst` and both `Mat` are containig grayscale images